# Deriving Taylor theorem expression

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

In one book, I've got a following written:

> Substituting for $f′(x)$ in (4.15), we obtain the second approximation:
>
> $$f(a +h) \approx f(a) + \int_a^{a+h}[f'(a) + (x-a)f''(a)]dx$$
>
> $$f(a +h) \approx f(a) +hf'(a) +\frac{h^2}{2}f''(a)$$

Okey, I'm getting the mechanics of Taylor approximation, but where this $\frac{1}{2}$ did get from in $\frac{h^2}{2}f''(a)$?

Edit:
In the book the first approximation in $x - a$ is written in the form
$$f(x) \approx f(a) +(x - a)f'(a)$$
the second as 
$$f'(x) \approx f'(a) +(x - a)f''(a)$$
and so on.

So, when $x = a + h$ in the upper limit of the integral those get in to the form of
$$f^n(a + h) \approx f^n(a) +hf^{n+1}(a)$$
Edit 2: The expression $f'(a) + (x-a)f''(a)$ is substituted in to the integral $\int_{a}^{a+h}f'(x)dx$.

Comment: Seems like a typo, one should replace $f'(x)$ with $f'(a) + (x-a)\cdot f''(a)$ rather than $f'(a) + h\cdot f''(a)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've added some info, and corrected the typo, but I'm not sure if it'll help.

Comment: If you integrate $\int_a^{a+h} (x-a)\cdot f''(a)\,dx$, what's the result?

Comment: No. Note that $f''(a)$ is a constant, you can pull that out of the integral. Then what remains is $\int_a^{a+h} (x-a)\,dx$. Substitute $t = x-a$.

Comment: I get $\frac{h^2}{2}$. Thank you!